# REGEX getting specific string and numbering

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following txt file:

```
VIII.  LOCATIONS:  OLA Handbook 1300.8, OPEN ARMS
                OLA Handbook 1300.21, BIG BROTHER
                

9.  RESTAURANTS:  ARBYS 22RX-60-81, same subject, dated March 20, 2018.
```

But I want to match anywhere with OLA Handbook and the numbers after it. But also be under the Locations section (so text after `LOCATIONS:`)

For example expected output would be:
How can i do this in regex?

```
 OLA Handbook 1300.8
 OLA Handbook 1300.21
```

SO far I've only done

```
(?=LOCATIONS).*$
```

But I'm confused how to proceed.

I'm using https://regex101.com/ to test my string and the txt file is from notepad ++.

Comment: Can you explain what this regex does?

Comment: Can you give a breakdown of "(\d*\.?\d+)" what is each individual regex statement doing here?

Comment: There is `LOCATIONS` in your pattern, should that be present?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yeah a solution that includes under the section "Locations" would be a preferred solution

Comment: @Eisen Can you update the question with the tool or language that you are using?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Updated

Comment: @Eisen You are using regex101 as the regex tool where you test your pattern. But I mean are you using a programming language or a tool like notepad++ for example?

Comment: Sorry i've updated to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

In notepad++ you can make use of the `\G` anchor to get continuous matches.

```
(?s)(?:\bLOCATIONS:|\G(?!^)).*?\b\KOLA\s+Handbook\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)\b
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `(?s)` Inline modifier, dot matches newline
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\bLOCATIONS:` Match literally, preceded by a word boundary to prevent a partial match
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at that start
- `)` Close non capture group
- `.*?` Match as least as possible chars
- `\b\K` A word boundary, then use `\K` to clear the current match buffer (forget what is matched until now)
- `OLA\s+Handbook\s+` Match the text, where `\s+` matches 1 or more whitespace chars
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)\b` Match 1+ digits and an optional decimal part and a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qWVR3N/1)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this exhausted code?

Find: `(ola.*\d)|.?`
Replace all: `$1`